# WalletConnect configuration for metamask mobile

Tags: react-native, mobile, expo, metamask, wallet-connect

Hey can anyone help me on below points-

1. Connect React Native(expo or xcode) Mobile App to Metamask Mobile Application with the help of Walletconnect

Not presenting the QRCode Modal but list of wallets available

2. Send Ethereum transaction to Metamask Mobile App

Please suggest an approach

Answer (score 0):

- wallet connect's dapp library https://www.npmjs.com/package/@walletconnect/react-native-dapp can be used to connect dApp with metamask wallet (List of wallets available on current device & which are supported by wallet connect will be displayed)
- To send Ethereum transaction use etherjs or wallet connect's web3provider using connector created above
  https://docs.walletconnect.com/quick-start/dapps/web3-provider

Answer (score 0):

So first you need to install react-native-dapp libbary. Here is the documentation https://docs.walletconnect.com/1.0/quick-start/dapps/react-native. If you'll have errors after installing read this https://levelup.gitconnected.com/tutorial-how-to-set-up-web3js-1-x-with-react-native-0-6x-2021-467b2e0c94a4 and do every suggested line. Here is my code from my project

```
    const connector = useWalletConnect();
    
    return (
    <View style={settingsScreenStyle.container}>
      {connector.connected && (
        <View style={{marginTop: 100}}>
          <Text style={settingsScreenStyle.text}>
            Hi, this is your Wallet Address {accountAddress}
          </Text>
          <Button
            title="Disconnect Wallet"
            onPress={() => {
              connector.killSession();
              disconnectWallet();
            }}
          />
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
```